# re-stash changes in git

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I am using git to track changes on some python scripts.

I have created a branch to make some changes on `script.py`. However, I am not yet ready to commit the changes. So, on the new `HL` (the real name is somewhat longer - please see screenshot below) branch that I created from master, I modified `script.py` and, as the production version of my python script is still on the master branch and I stashed the changes and it is all fine, I can checkout back to master. If I now do `git stash list` I get

```
stash@{0}: WIP on HL: 710c540 rm cached files not to track
```

I now want to go back to branch `HL` and keep working on that stashed change. For that, on VS code ([gitlens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=eamodio.gitlens) extension enabled) I clicked on apply stash, which I believe is similar to `git stash apply stash@{0}`

[image]

But now, if I am finished with my changes (or I did not change `script.py` at all), it appears I need to create a new stash, with a new ID `stash@{1}`, in order to checkout back to the (unchanged) master branch

Is there a way (preferably on vs code, but also command line) to 're-stash' the changes (if any - in my case I did not change anything) to the same stash `stash@{0}`)? Like so I would avoid the creation of a new stash, identical to the current one that I already have.

Comment: Nearly every premise of this question seems mistaken. Don't misuse stashes for this. Make a wip commit. Maybe even give it a branch name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Git stash actually represents 2 (and sometimes 3) commits.  So, to modify an existing stash we would semantically have to amend those stash commits.  I don't even know if this would be readily possible, and even if it were, it would be very atypical workflow.

Instead, aasuming you have applied your previous stash and are happy with the result, just drop the previous stash:

```
git stash drop stash@{0}
```

Then, simply make a new stash from your current point.  That being said, it is also good practice to favor `git stash apply` over `git stash pop`, for the reason that you might have occasion to use the stash again.  There is nothing wrong with maintaining a reasonably-sized stash history.